# CSRF Attacks on the Authorization Server via the Implicit Flow?

Tags: security, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, openid-connect

In [this article](https://spring.io/blog/2011/11/30/cross-site-request-forgery-and-oauth2) the section on implicit grant attacks has two scenarios.  One where the attacker has both the clientid and secret and one where the attacker has only the clientid.

I'm trying to figure out how (If this type of attack is even possible) the attack would work, since IIUC the implicit flow does not use the `client secret` at all (Is this a realistic scenario)?

Comment: seems the article is out of date: as you correctly state, the Implicit flow does not use a client secret